# ASP C# UpdatePanel does not update contents

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webforms, updatepanel

I am trying to update the datasource of a webdatagrid in an updatepanel. I am able to do this via a timer `tick` event

```
<asp:timer id="Timer1" runat="server" interval="10000" ontick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:timer>
<asp:updatepanel id="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick"/>
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <ig:WebDataGrid ID="WebDataGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
        </ig:WebDataGrid>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:updatepanel>
```

And with the `Tick` event handler

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebDataGrid.DataSource = *a datatable*;
    WebDataGrid.DataBind();
}
```

However, now when I try to do the same thing except instead of using the timer, use the `WebDataGridMain_RowSelectionChanged` event instead the webdatagrid does not update. I believe the new datasource value is still being sent to the client however the `UpdatePanel` does not seem to be updating the view.

```
<ig:WebDataGrid ID="WebDataGridMain" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowSelectionChanged="WebDataGridMain_RowSelectionChanged">
    <ClientEvents AJAXResponse="AJAXResponseHandler" />
</ig:WebDataGrid>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="WebDataGridMain" EventName="RowSelectionChanged"/>
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <ig:WebDataGrid ID="WebDataGridDetail" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            </ig:WebDataGrid>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

With the the similar event handler code below

```
protected void WebDataGridMain_RowSelectionChanged(object sender, Infragistics.Web.UI.GridControls.SelectedRowEventArgs e)
{
    WebDataGridDetail.DataSource = *a datatable*;
    WebDataGridDetail.DataBind();
}
```

There doesn't seem to be any difference between these two except for the type of event trigger. What should I change so that the `UpdatePanel` works with the `RowSelectionChanged` event?